# Knex multiple primary key in a identify relationship where id is an auto increment column

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, knex.js, composite-primary-key

I tried to use every single logic in my mind to resolve this problem, but this is the only solution that it worked.

```
knex.schema.createTable('documents', (table) => {
      table.integer('id').unsigned().notNullable().unique()
      table.string('path')
      table.enum('type', ['CPF', 'RG'])
      table.integer('user_id').unsigned().notNullable()
      table.foreign('user_id').references('id').inTable('users')
      table.primary(['id', 'user_id'])

      table.timestamps(true, true)
    })
    knex.schema.alterTable(this.tableName, (table) => {
      table.increments('id', { primaryKey: false }).alter()
    })
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This topic isn't a question, this is the way that I found to solve the problem using multiple primary key, where an id is auto_increment in the table.